# How do I runtime-instantiate a generic type in F#?

Tags: generics, f#

I wish I could do the following:

```
type Logger = {
    warn : System.Type -> string -> unit
    // also methods for error, info etc
}

// during application startup
let warn (serviceProvider : IServiceProvider) (t : Type) s =
    let loggerType = typeof<ILogger<'a>>.MakeGenericType(t)
    let logger = serviceProvider.GetService(loggerType) :?> ILogger
    logger.LogWarning(s)

let log = { warn = warn; ... } // with similar setups for info, error etc
```

Then, I'd be able to partially apply with `log`, and deep inside the app I could

```
log.warn typeof<Foo> "a warning message"
```

which would log a message using the type `Foo` to determine the [log category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-category).

The troublesome expression is

```
typeof<ILogger<'a>>.MakeGenericType(t)
```

where F# seems to infer the type of `'a` in the generic definition to be `obj`, and so the call to `MakeGenericType` fails with an exception saying that the type definition I'm calling it on is not generic.

The equivalent C# would be

```
typeof(ILogger<>).MakeGenericType(t)
```

but `typeof<ILogger<>>` doesn't compile in F#.

How do I instantiate a generic type like this, where the type argument is only known at runtime, in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is `typedefof<ILogger<_>>` - that will give you the non-instantiated type `ILooger<_>`, on which you can then call `MakeGenericType`.

However, I would rather recommend you rethink your architecture. Why instantiate types at runtime? That's slower and less safe. In this case, I see no reason to do it.

Better pass your types as generic parameters. Of course you can't have record members be generic functions, so that's a bummer. However, F# does offer another facility for this sort of thing - interfaces. Interface methods can be fully generic:

```
type Logger =
    abstract member warn<'logger> : string -> unit

let mkLog (serviceProvider : IServiceProvider) =
    { new Logger with
        member warn<'logger> s =
            let logger = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof<ILogger<'logger>>) :?> ILogger
            logger.LogWarning(s)
    }

let log = mkLog serviceProvider

// usage:
log.warn<Foo> "a warning message"
```

Granted, the syntax for creating an instance of such type is a bit clunky, but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Thanks! By including more detail about my design than absolutely necessary, I was actually hoping someone would suggest a better design ;) The interface approach lacks the ability to deconstruct, though - do you know if there is any way I can deconstruct the logger created with this approach using pattern matching?

Comment: Custom matcher (aka "active pattern")? I can't really say anything sensible until I know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Yeah, an active pattern probably works. Before using an interface instead of a record for the log, I was deconstructing like `doSomeStuff { warn = warn } ...` in method signatures in a few places; I was thinking if there was a way to retain that functionality. But it's probably not a good idea anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

The F# equivalent of `typeof(ILogger<>)` in C# is to use the `typedefof` function:

```
typedefof<ILogger<_>>.MakeGenericType(t)
```

This is still a normal function that takes a fully instantiated type - the `_` placeholder will be automatically filled with `obj`, but the `typedefof` function does not return the type, but its generic type definition. You could also do the same by calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on the result of `typeof`, but `typedefof` is a nicer shortcut!